# Should function call go before or after brackets that wrap function body?

Tags: javascript, coding-style, iife

Both

```
(function () {
    // do something
)();
```

and

```
(function () {
    // do something
());
```

work fine. I wonder what is the conventional way to define an IIFE? And why?

Comment: There is no difference. This is a duplicate and I'll close it as soon as I can find the right question via the always infuriatingly inadequate SO search.